# Contain mesh within another mesh boundaries?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, masking, artifacts

I'm trying to limit a mesh within certain boundaries so that I can then scale it really big and the mesh never goes out of boundaries of a box.

I've tried using boolean but I get a plethora of strange artifacts. The mask modifier (as I understand it) only accounts same-mesh vertex groups. This wouldn't cut it, since when I scale the mesh I need the box to remain the same size.
I'm trying not to resort to hiding it via compositing, but if that's the only other way, I'll see what I can work around with that.

Do any of you know how can I achieve something like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful to know the visual result you are seeking for the viewers of your work.  What is the visual result you are seeking? Should the mesh fill the box? A guess would be inflating. At this point IMHO the question is a little vague and difficult to understand.

Comment: Scaling is just one way of changing shape. Have you used others? Is there some particular reason you want to use Scaling?

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't know how to phrase it properly at the time. Here are pictures. 

[Small](https://imgur.com/a/aZj9qJ6) - [Big](https://imgur.com/a/v5uOLVg)

I attempted using several boxes in boolean mode to mask it out but only one of them appears to work.. for the most part.

Comment: If possible your pictures should be in the question itself.  I am not able to understand your problem.  Perhaps you should delete the question and try to rephrase it.  When the reader is guessing the description of  the problem, we have created yet another problem.

Comment: Your images should be in the original question.  People should not be able to see images not related to the BSE question.

Comment: Please show your work.  Any modifiers and textures and UV Maps.   Still guessing on your goals and your techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Geometry Nodes group:

[image]

... can independently clamp the X,Y and Z coordinates of the modified mesh to a given box-object:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider scaling and translating your UV coordinates for a texture producing a displacement.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way is using some kind of alpha / transparency on material level...
[here's an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggzf7zpu52ai2bq/MASK.blend?dl=1), just to add some other option, this seems to be an old question

Comment: The accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for, but this is indeed a neat trick.